# if/else Logic in Eloquent Query

Tags: if-statement, model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to be able to query a model based on specific criteria within a route closure.

I have this route:

```
Route::get('courses/{category_slug}/{slug}', function($category_slug, $slug) {
    $category = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->first();

    $course = Course::leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'courses.category_id')
        ->where('categories.slug', '=', $category_slug)
        ->where('courses.slug', '=', $slug)
        ->orWhere('categories.parent_id', '=', $category->id)
        ->where('categories.slug', '=', $slug)
        ->firstOrFail();

    return View::make('courses.show')->with('course', $course);
});
```

This partially works but I need to be able to either use get() or firstOrFail() depending on whether the route points to a sub-category or an actual page.

It would also be nice to change the name of the variable based on this criteria, as well as the return value to use a different blade template.

Is this approach feasible? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I almost have it working using:

http://paste.laravel.com/zod

The problem is, if the query for $sub_category doesn't return anything I get a model not found error.

Comment: Just use `first` if you don't want an error thrown. Then check if the `$sub_category` is null to ensure you got a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it working using:

```
Route::get('courses/{category_slug}/{slug}', function($category_slug, $slug) {
    $category = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->first();
    $sub_category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    if (!is_null($sub_category)) {
        if ($sub_category->slug === $slug) {
            $courses = Course::leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'courses.category_id')
                ->where('categories.parent_id', '=', $category->id)
                ->where('categories.slug', '=', $slug)
                ->get();

            return View::make('courses.index')->with('courses', $courses);
        }
    } else {
        $course = Course::leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'courses.category_id')
            ->where('categories.slug', '=', $category_slug)
            ->where('courses.slug', '=', $slug)
            ->firstOrfail();

        return View::make('courses.show')->with('course', $course);
    }
});
```

There is probably a better way, so if anyone can shed some light on it that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone bumping in same problem, You can use the capability of the eloquent query builder to avoid duplication:

```
Route::get('courses/{category_slug}/{slug}', function($category_slug, $slug) {
    $category = Category::where('slug', $category_slug)->first();
    $sub_category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $course_query = Course::leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'courses.category_id')
                ->where('categories.parent_id', '=', $category->id)
                ->where('categories.slug', '=', $slug)

    if (!is_null($sub_category)) {
        if ($sub_category->slug === $slug) {
            $courses = $course_query->get();

            return View::make('courses.index')->with('courses', $courses);
        }
    } else {
        $course = $course_query->firstOrfail();

        return View::make('courses.show')->with('course', $course);
    }
});
```

We create a common query `$course_query` that we can use below many times, avoiding duplication.
Note: `$course_query` declaration must have no `get()`, `firstOrFail()` or `first()`!